# API to get all user's actions history

Tags: beatsmusic

There seems to be an api to post "play" events, but no way to retrieve user's play history. Can you suggest a way to do that?

It would be great to also get user's "love" and "ban" track events as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to pull this data, right now.

Comment: Is it in the plans? This would be extremely useful!

Comment: @Aeon - We agree this is great data. It's not planned in the immediate future, but something we are looking at.